# understanding an inequality on pg.136 Royden (4th edition).

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> For any two numbers $a$ and $b$,
>   $$
> |a+b| \le |a| + |b| \le 2 \max \{ |a|, |b| \},
> $$
>   and hence
>   $$
> |a+b|^p \le 2^p \left( |a|^p + |b|^p\right).
> $$

But I do not understand how the last inequality comes from the one that precedes it, could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|a+b|^p \leq 2^p (\max\{|a|,|b|\})^p$

1.If $\max\{|a|,|b|\}=|a|$ then $(\max\{|a|,|b|\})^p=|a|^p \leq |a|^p+|b|^p$

2.If $\max\{|a|,|b|\}=|b|$ then $(\max\{|a|,|b|\})^p=|b|^p \leq |a|^p+|b|^p$

So in either case $2^p (\max\{|a|,|b|\})^p\leq 2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p)$

Answer (score 4):

If $p \ge 0$ then $ t \mapsto t^p$ is monotonically increasing, so that
$$
 |a+b| \le 2 \max(|a|, |b|)
$$
implies that
$$
|a+b|^p \le 2^p \bigl(\max(|a|, |b|) \bigr)^p =  2^p \max(|a|^p, |b|^p)
 \le 2^p (|a|^p + |b|^p) \, .
$$

For $p < 0$ the inequality is wrong: Choose $a > 0$ and $b = 0$, then
$$
 |a+b|^p = |a|^p > 2^p |a|^p  = 2^p (|a|^p + |b|^p) \, .
$$

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$|a+b| \le 2\max\{|a|,|b|\}$$
Without loss of generality, let us say that $\max\{|a|,|b|\} = |a|$. Then, the above inequality implies:
$$|a+b|\le 2|a| \Rightarrow |a+b|^{p}\le 2^{p}|a|^{p} \le 2^{p}(|a|^{p}+|b|^{p})$$
Because $|b|^{p} \ge 0$.